# Mix MSAL and MVC Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, forms-authentication, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm working on a single tenant MVC web app with multiple users. There are multiple deployments of this app for different customers and some customers would like to send mail via Outlook 365. The app uses forms authentication with users stored in the database.

I've attempted to get something working based on the following sample - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect - however it conflicts with the forms authentication in that I get looped back to the forms login page even if log in is successful.

I can successfully retrieve an access token by directing the user to the Azure AD sign in after successful login:

```
var url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?" +
                "client_id=" + AuthenticationConfig.ClientId +
                "&response_type=code" +
                "&redirect_uri=" + AuthenticationConfig.RedirectUri +
                "&response_mode=query" +
                "&scope=" + AuthenticationConfig.BasicSignInScopes +
                "&state=12345";
```

Then in the callback use the following to get the access token:

```
       public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string code)
    {
        var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(AuthenticationConfig.ClientId)
                    .WithClientSecret(AuthenticationConfig.ClientSecret)
                    .WithRedirectUri(AuthenticationConfig.RedirectUri)
                    .WithAuthority(AuthenticationConfig.Authority)
                    .Build();

        var scopes = new List<string> { "offline_access", "user.read", "mail.read", "mail.send" };    
        var authenticationResult = await app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, code).ExecuteAsync();
        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }
```

However no refresh token is returned in the authentication result. I'd hoped to get the access token/expiry and refresh token/expiry and store them so the user would authenticate once via Azure AD and then I could silently renew the access token using the refresh token in the future.

I've done a lot of reading but most of the information I can find is based on using Azure AD login for your app. I need to retain the forms login and authenticate for the purpose sending email only. Is this possible?

UPDATE to attempt to cache the token against the user and read it back:

```
        public static async Task OnAuthorisationCodeReceived(string code)
    {
        var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                   .Create(AuthenticationConfig.ClientId)
                   .WithClientSecret(AuthenticationConfig.ClientSecret)
                   .WithRedirectUri(AuthenticationConfig.RedirectUri)
                   .WithAuthority(AuthenticationConfig.Authority)
                   .Build();

        var scopes = new List<string> { "offline_access", "user.read", "mail.read", "mail.send" };
        var authenticationResult = await app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, code).ExecuteAsync();
        var account = authenticationResult.Account;

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimConstants.ObjectId, account.HomeAccountId.ObjectId));
        identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimConstants.TenantId, account.HomeAccountId.TenantId));
        identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Upn, account.Username));
        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        // as per example store the cache
        var userTokenCache = new MSALPerUserMemoryTokenCache(app.UserTokenCache, claimsPrincipal);
        // no accounts returned
        var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

        var newres = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

There are no accounts returned, the only way I can see cached tokens is if I leave the default so they're not stored against the user.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MSAL.NET (and MSALs in general) doesn't expose the refresh token.

You can see that there is not "refreshToken" in AuthenticationResult.

you can handle refreshing token automatically by calling AcquireTokenSilent.

Comment: Using AcquireTokenSilent works when I run an app with Azure AD for authentication but I'm having trouble with caching in my forms authentication app. See updated code above.